# Is the story ever evolved?

Tags: the-prisoner

Watching *The Prisoner* for the first time I have seen 3 episodes now.

While I find the setting intriguing, I get the feeling that the situation won't change. That at the end of each episode we will not really have learned more of why he resigned, who runs the village and why, where it is located, etc.

I am curious about these questions if I am to continue watching the series:

- Will we gradually learn more about the background of nbr 6 and the village?
- Will the questions be answered at the end of the last episode?

  - If yes, will the questions be answered *only* in the last episode?

Comment: You've waited 50-odd years to watch it & you can't let the plot come to you as it happens??

Comment: Incorrect. I have not waited for it. I want to know if there is a plan behind the writing and not just like with so many other shows, a great mystery is created by the writers while they have no clue how to actually resolve it.

Comment: It does evolve toward something different but you'll have to watch it to decide for yourself whether it provides satisfying answers. The series' ending has troubled a lot of people. It took me quite a while to come to terms with it myself. But I do love this show.

Comment: Iirc (seen it a long time ago), you won't gather much of that info from most episodes. The show is more about a reflection on our own societies and how they work. There is a clear ending, though... Pretty revolutionary show for the time.

Comment: Or just read the Wikipedia page?

Comment: It's hard to know how to answer this. In terms of "does it have a planned complete story arc", it's not, say, _Lost_; but it's also not _Babylon 5_. How do you quantify that?

Comment: I agree with @AakashM. Plus I would argue that just because writers didn't plan a story out from the get-go, necessarily means it won't have a good or substantial ending that answers the tenor of it's major questions.

Answer (score 3):

Are the questions answered at the end of the series?  Sort of.  The last two episodes do provide some answers.

We find out who is No.1.   We see a hint at where The Village is, although it contradicts earlier hints in the series.

The ending makes you think about the state of the world.  The whole series is meant to make you think.

The power of the allegory and the cinematography make this still arguably the best TV series ever made. You still see homages to its key scenes in modern productions.

Comment: Plus Iron Maiden wrote a couple songs about it, so there's that.